# Custom null assertion in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, .net-core, rider

I have a custom extension method for checking `Guid?` values:

```
public static bool IsNullOrDefault(this Guid? guid)
{
    return !guid.HasValue || guid.value == Guid.Empty;
}
```

When I use the method in my code, I would expect that Rider will consider this method in possible System.InvalidOperationException assertions. But it does not.

```
public void Foo(Guid? guid)
{
    if (guid.IsNullOrDefault())
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    var x = guid.Value;
            ^ There is still a yellow squiggle here, saying Possible System.InvalidOperationException
    ...
}
```

I have tried creating my own Null Checking pattern by overwriting the Custom (statement) pattern:

```
if ($EXPR$.IsNullOrDefault()) throw new System.ArgumentNullException($NAME$);
```

But that does not work either. How can I configure Rider to consider my custom method an equivalent to `guid.HasValue` or `guid != null`?

Comment: If you used `guid == null` rather than `!guid.HasValue` does it act the way you expected?

Comment: Does https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206717395-Annotation-to-prevent-possible-null-reference-exception-warning- help?

Comment: @mjwills `guid == null` does not help. I have to check the annotations first... but I have some concerns, since part of the team is still using Visual Studio, that they might be missing the JetBrains annotations assemblies.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure Rider is intelligent enough to recognize that you already checked this.
I think what you can do instead, is use the `?.` notation to check for `null`

```
var x = guid?.Value;
```

This check if `guid` is `null` before the `.value` is evaluated, and just return `null` if that's the case.

Then you can put the check afterward instead, so it ends up like

```
var x guid?.value;
if(x is null)
    Throw new Exception();
```

Or you can return a default value instead of throwing an exception, your call.

Let me know how it works!

Comment: I am sorry, but this defeats the whole purpose of having a custom extension method for null checking.

Comment: Couldn't you still use it though? Just instead of the `if(x is null)` i suggested, you could write your `if(guid.IsNullOrDefault())` and it would behave the same way.

Or alternatively, you can just modify your original example with `var x = guid?.Value;` and it would go away.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question! I just googled "rider add custom null check" and got this question. Which is the question I have as well. But you are not answering the question. Down voted.